# Reducing Font and Circle size in FontAwesome

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML snippet with the following output:

```
<div id="share">

  <!-- facebook -->
  <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{url}}&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></i>3232</a>

  <!-- twitter -->
  <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status={{title}}+{{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i>232</a>

  <!-- google plus -->
  <a class="googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>532</a>

  <!-- linkedin -->
  <a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{url}}&title={{title}}&source={{source}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-1x"></i>242</a>

  <!-- pinterest -->
  <a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media={{media}}&url={{url}}&is_video=false&description={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i>125</a>

</div>
```

I am using FontAwesome. As you can see, the text is overflowing in the output.

Can I move the icons (f, G+ etc) upwards a little bit, and also reduce the size of the circle, including font of the icon and numbers?

[image: Overflowing text]

I have used the `fa-1x` class as well but that doesn't help. Here's the entire CSS and HTML

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyrBNJ)

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove this rule `#share i`

then add this rule:

```
i.fa {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

and reduce the `#share a` `font-size` to `16px`, that's it.

Check the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/mpRjQr)

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution!

Comment: How can I move all the contents of the div to left. Currently it is centered as seen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYydvq

Comment: you are welcome :) , you could accept my answer as the right answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: remove `text-align: center;` from `#share` and add it to `#share a` instead, https://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/LexqaJ

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you can wrap `text` with a `span` then play with `font-size`.

```css
#share a span {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

/* container */

#share {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* buttons */

#share a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

#share a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* icons */

#share i {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


/* colors */

.facebook {
  background: #3b5998;
  font-size: 2px;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55acee;
}

.googleplus {
  background: #dd4b39;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #0077b5;
}

.pinterest {
  background: #cb2027;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="share">

  <!-- facebook -->
  <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{url}}&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></i><span>3232</span></a>

  <!-- twitter -->
  <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status={{title}}+{{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i><span>232</span></a>

  <!-- google plus -->
  <a class="googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>532</span></a>

  <!-- linkedin -->
  <a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{url}}&title={{title}}&source={{source}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-1x"></i><span>242</span></a>

  <!-- pinterest -->
  <a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media={{media}}&url={{url}}&is_video=false&description={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i><span>125</span></a>

</div>
```

**Second version:**

```css
#share span {
  display: block;
}

#share div {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* container */

#share {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* buttons */

#share a {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

#share a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* icons */

#share i {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* colors */

.facebook {
  background: #3b5998;
  font-size: 2px;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55acee;
}

.googleplus {
  background: #dd4b39;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #0077b5;
}

.pinterest {
  background: #cb2027;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="share">

  <!-- facebook -->
  <div><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{url}}&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></i></a><span>3232</span></div>

  <!-- twitter -->
  <div><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status={{title}}+{{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i></a><span>232</span></div>

  <!-- google plus -->
  <div><a class="googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a><span>532</span></div>

  <!-- linkedin -->
  <div><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{url}}&title={{title}}&source={{source}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-1x"></i></a><span>242</span>
  </div>

  <!-- pinterest -->
  <div><a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media={{media}}&url={{url}}&is_video=false&description={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
    <span>125</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good way to achieve the solution. I wish the font was of a lower size.

Comment: Any way to bring the text under the circle and then reduce the circle size too?

Comment: @IWantToLearn Yes, see updated answer, second snippet.

Comment: Very helpful. One last question. When I put this div inside another div that contains text, everything goes haywire. Do you have any idea as to how to adapt the share div to "just fit" in it's parent div.

Comment: I have no idea what's the problem exactly, i should see, try to update your answer with this problem or add a new question @IWantToLearn

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rules to the CSS:

```
#share a {
    display: inline-grid;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none; /* Personal taste */
}
```

Here is an updated version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEWBXp?editors=1100, note that the icons are not centered or the text will not fit in the circle.

Comment: It tends to throw the text out of the circle. Try putting it to 12px.

Comment: @IWantToLearn yes, the text would go outside the circle because this element and the `<i>`'s are siblings. This can be fixed placing a `<br/>` in between or simply using an `inline-grid`. Take a look at the updated version.

Comment: Fantastic! Just for the purposes of learning, can we pull the count text outside the circle (below it) and reduce the overall size of the circle?